# SQL server Data types - Date VS Varchar(n)

Tags: sql-server-2008, varchar, sqldatatypes

I have developed a system where i store my Date values in Varchar(n) column. now i have been asked to change the column's data type to Date.
my Date format is dd/mm/yyyy, and i have more than 2000 records in the table containing this Date column which is of type varchar. what is the best way to change the data type of the column from varchar to Date without compromising the existing data? and i wanted to know what are the downsides in storing Date values in a varchar column and what are the advantages in storing the Date values in Varchar Data Type. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee your column contains only dates of the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, and given a column named `DateColumnToChange` on table `AlterColumnTest`, you can do something like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
ALTER TABLE [AlterColumnTest]
ALTER COLUMN DateColumnToChange DATETIME
```

The first line will ensure that for the scope of your script, the date format will be set to day-month-year.

Then the alter statement will attempt to change the Type of your column but will first try to do an implicit cast of your current values to DateTime. If this fails, the type of your column will not change. If all values can be cast to a DateTime, it will change the column type to DateTime and all values in there should now be of type DateTime.

The reasons for storing Date and Time values as a specific type is the same reason that, in strongly typed languages, we specify specific variable types. It gives you an added layer of security when dealing with your data. Your queries also know what kind of data you're holding in there and will optimise for such. It will make column and data comparisons much easier as you can leverage built-in comparisons, without the need for explicit casting (checking if a date is earlier than one provided for example).

There are really no reasons I can think of (but do correct me in comments if I'm wrong) for not storing DateTime values in anything else but a DateTime typed column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try it out and post my result ASAP.

Comment: i tried out your way, i inserted two date values in the format of dd/mm/yyyy in a varchar column, and then altered the columns data type to Date (as i am not storing time so i used Date) and it altered the column just fine but when i queried the column the Dates i got as a result was in yyyy-mm-dd format so not ideally what i want . i dont want the format of the dates changed when i change the data type of the column. so any other ideas would be great.

Comment: the collation of the column is by default SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS by the way because i think it has something to do with that aswell.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest changing collations. If you need to display the dates in a different format, you'll have to `CONVERT` then and pass in a format. Right now your dates are stored as datetimes and that was the scope of the question. Depending on how you want to present your data, you can now either CONVERT them in your queries or `.ToString()` (in the case of C#) them to suit your displaying needs.

Comment: when you say 'SET DATEFORMAT dmy' what exactly does it do? does it tell the server that the columns which is being altered has data in dmy format or doest it change the format of the date for all the operations to dmy, if its the second case then it isnt working as expected because as i told you the dates still gets stored in yyyy-mm-dd  format. and if there is a way to store that dates in dd/mm/yyyy format in  a Date column please suggest because its important.

Comment: i ran the command `DBCC useroptions` and as a result i got `language=British` and `Dateformat=dmy` then why is it still getting stored as `yyyy-mm-dd` ?